# How to display static block from template file based on some condition in magento Product View page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to display static block based on some condition like:

```
if($_product->getPrice() >= 100){
   //Static Block display code.
}
else{
   //Some other static block display code.
}
```

Is it possible? I don't mind displaying code the xml layout way, but I want to display the code in condition.How to do that? Please anybody can solve this?

Comment: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-call-static-block-from-template-file/

Comment: may be refer this too http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-call-block-directly-from-phtml-file-without-defining-in-layout/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
if($_product->getPrice() >= 100){
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace/block1')->setTemplate('namespace/block1.phtml')->toHtml();
} else {
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace/block2')->setTemplate('namespace/block2.phtml')->toHtml();
}
```

Block files need to be stored inside app/design/frontend//default/template/

In the presented case: app/design/frontend//default/template/namespace/block1.phtml

Comment: yeah it worked, thnx, I wanted to display on sidebar, now they are displayed, with some editing in templates and blocks. :) thnx again.